# Can you Navigate from inside a UICommand on a MessageDialog?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to do `Page` navigation from inside of a `UICommand` on a `MessageDialog`, but I can't get it to work.

Here I have a `UICommand` that calls for `Page` navigation if a user declines to accept the terms of agreement for my application.

```
var decline = new UICommand("No, I Decline", async command =>
{
    await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
         (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Navigate(typeof(LoginPage));
    });
});
commands.Add(decline);
```

But when executed on the UI thread or not that `Page` won't navigate.

Here is a simple `ShowDialogue` method:

```
public static async void ShowDialogue(string message, string title, IEnumerable<UICommand> commands)
    {
        var Dispatcher = CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
        {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog(message, title);

            foreach (var command in commands)
            {
                dialog.Commands.Add(command);
            }

            dialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 0;
            dialog.CancelCommandIndex = 1;

            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        });
    }
```

EDIT:

My issue was here:

```
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (allowToLeavePage == false)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }

        displayRequest.RequestRelease();
    }
```

In my code I didn't realize I was blocking page navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce your issue on my side. I invoked the `ShowDialogue` method inside a button click event handle. The completed code snippet which can work well for invoking the above `ShowDialogue` method is as follows:

```
private void optest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string message = "message test";
    string title = "title test";
    List<UICommand> commands = new List<UICommand>();
    var decline = new UICommand("No, I Decline", async command =>
    {
        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Navigate(typeof(LoginPage));
        });
    });
    commands.Add(decline);
    ShowDialogue(message, title, commands); 
}
```

My UWP app target version is build 16299. If you still have issues, please provide a completed minimal reproduced project. More details please reference [`MessageDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog).

One more thing, you should use `MessageDialog` only when you are upgrading a Universal Windows 8 app that uses `MessageDialog`, and need to minimize changes. For new apps in Windows 10, we recommend using the [`ContentDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog)control instead. See the "Important" section of `MessageDialog` class.

Comment: I did see that ContentDialog note... It does take more effort to use